# simple detection algorithm

Tags: objective-c, c, algorithm

i'm working on a simple multiplayer game that receives a random 4x4 matrix from a server and extracting a shape from it

for example:

```
XXOO
XXOX
XOOX
XXXX

OXOO
XXOO
XOOO
OXXX
```

so in the first matrix the shape i want to parse is this:

```
 oo
 o
oo
```

and the 2nd:

```
  oo
  oo
 ooo
```

i know there must be an algorithm for this because i saw this kind of behavior on some puzzle games but i have no idea how to go about to detect them or even have an idea where to start

so my question is:how do i detect what shape is in the matrix and how do i differentiate between multiple colors? (aka..it doesn't come only in x and o..it comes in a maximum of 4)

note: the shape must be a minimum of 4 blocks

Comment: Are you just trying to extract the largest contiguous group of "O"s? This question needs more detail and context.

Comment: What if there is more than one "shape" (e.g. the first and last columns being all O's). The algorithm will be easy once you have a clear definition of "shape".

Comment: yes the largest shape of a certain color

Comment: the way i generate the matrix on the server side...there can't be more than one shape of size 4+

Comment: Is there only one shape, or are you trying to solve for the *biggest* shape?

Comment: there's only one shape but as you see in the 2nd example there could be a stray "o" that can be considered a shape

Comment: This is a simple boolean algebra problem.  Your patterns above can be represented in a single 16-bit value, and you can use a combo of AND/OR/XOR with a mask to see if the value matches one of your pattern masks.  Shifting the value and/or mask will let you play with different alignments of the pattern (though you need to be cognizant of when a pattern "falls off the edge").

Answer (score 0):

It's not fully clear what you want to do, but it seems like you want to extract some sort of shape (based on the second example, top left `O` not being included).  I'd think about traversing the array, and for each cell, check for neighboring `O`s.  Discount the duplicates you're likely to count (maybe by only looking at neighbors below and to the right of the cell you're examining).  Then, if it meets whatever criteria you want for a 'shape'.  Maybe if you give more examples or a better description, we can be more accurate.  Or give it a shot yourself and post where you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this :

```
1. Assign integer values to each position in the matrix, like this, [1,2,3,4
                                                                     5,6,7,8 
                                                                     9,10,11,12
                                                                     13,14,15,16].
2.Read the position of zeroes. (I guess, shapes correpond to '0' s located either horizontally  or  vertically aligned). Store them in an array. So, for first case your array will read [3,4,7,11,10]


 2. Then Start 'drawing' the shape.
       1. First value 3. so shape= 0.
       2. Next value  4. Check if it is consecutive to any other value in the array. that value is 3. so the shape = 00
        3. Next val= 7. Is it consecutive ? no. Is it 4 more than any other value? yes, 3. So it goes below 3. shape= 00 
                        0
       4. Next 11, similar to step3, it goes below 7. shape= 00
                                                             0
                                                             0
       5. Next 10, it is one less than 11, so it is placed before 11. shape= 00
                                                                             0
                                                                            00.
```

You can do some optimizations, like for consecutive, only check the prev. val in the array.
For vertical, check only four prev values.

Also, dont forget to special conditions for boundary values like 4 & 5. I dont they will make a shape.